# Making curved labels for polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have been able to find answers on how to do this in older versions of QGIS, but can't seem to come across anything that deals with the latest installment.

I need a way to make labels curve to irregularly shaped polygons; in this case rivers.

I have been assuming that this option would be listed under "Placement" in the "Labels" options but have been unable to find it anywhere.

I know it was present up until QGIS 2.2 and think it must be included in 2.6.1. I'm just not seeing it.

I am aware of the Easy custom labeling plugin curved option, but that doesn't seem to work as it should.

Comment: You have river polygons, not lines? There are no curved polygon labels.

Comment: @underdark can the op simplify the polygons into lines, make them invisible and have the rounded labels? I'm not sure if it'll work, just guessing out loud

Comment: might be easiest to manually draw the lines for the labels rather than bothering with simplification - if the no. features is not too big

Comment: @underdark Sorry, that's my bad. Chalk it up to my inexperience. I hadn't considered the notion that the problem I was having was that I had a polygon rather than a line. Although it'd be a useful feature, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there are no curved polygon labels.

As dassouki suggested, you can use different approaches to create lines which can then be labeled with curved labels. It might be easiest to just draw some labeling lines manually - if the number of features in question is not too high.